# What are the functionalities that Cypress doesn't work for Mobile Browser testing?

Tags: cypress

The FAQ section of Cypress documentation says that

> "Cypress will never be able to run on a native mobile app, but we can
>   test some functionality of mobile web browsers."

It says, we can test some functionality of mobile web browsers. What does it mean? Does it mean that there are some functionalities we can't test for mobile web browsers that we can do for normal browsers. If so, can you please tell what are they?

Answer (score 0):

All of the supported Chrome-family browsers (including Electron) and beta supported Firefox browser can simulate mobile devices with Device Mode.

This option can be enabled through the developer tools. See the documentation for Google Chrome here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode

---

The answer to the FAQ you referenced, ["Do you support native mobile apps?"](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/general-questions-faq.html#Do-you-support-native-mobile-apps), is suggesting that the Cypress Test Runner will never run on mobile operating systems such as iOS or Android, and therefor it will not be able to target an actual mobile browser such as Safari or Google Chrome (Mobile).